# Kubernetes Deployment: preStop does not execute aws commands

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-deployment

I am trying to transfer logs over to S3 just before the pod is terminated. For this, we need to

1. Configure our container to have AWS-CLI. I did this successfully
   using a script in postStart hook.
2. Execute AWS S3 command to transfer files from a hostPath to S3
   bucket. Almost had this one !!!

Here is my Kube Deployment (running on minikube):

```html
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: logtransfer-poc
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: logs
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: secret-resources
        secret:
          secretName: local-secrets
      - name: testdata
        hostPath:
          path: /data/testdata
      containers:
        - name: logtransfer-poc
          image: someImage
          ports:
          - name: https-port
            containerPort: 8443
          command: ["/bin/bash","-c","--"]
          args: ["while true; do sleep 30; done;"]
          volumeMounts:
          - name: secret-resources
            mountPath: "/data/apache-tomcat/tomcat/resources"
          - name: testdata
            mountPath: "/data/testdata"
          lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "cd /data/testdata/ && chmod u+x installS3Script.sh && ./installS3Script.sh > postInstall.logs"]
            preStop:
              exec:
                command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "cd /data/testdata/ && chmod u+x transferFilesToS3.sh && ./transferFilesToS3.sh > postTransfer.logs"]
          terminationMessagePath: /data/testdata/termination-log
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: my-docker-credentials
```

installS3Script.sh

```html
#!/bin/bash

apt-get update
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py --user
chmod u+x get-pip.py
echo "PATH=$PATH:/root/.local/bin" >> ~/.bashrc && echo "Path Exported !!"
source ~/.bashrc && echo "Refreshed profile !"
pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user
mkdir -p ~/.aws
cp /data/testdata/config/config ~/.aws
cp /data/testdata/config/credentials ~/.aws
```

transferFilesToS3.sh

```html
#!/bin/bash

# export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=admin
echo "Transfering files to S3.."
aws s3 cp /data/testdata/data s3://testpratham --recursive --profile admin
aws s3 ls s3://testpratham --profile admin
echo "Transfer to S3 successfull !!"
```

What failed: the transferFilesToS3.sh runs successfully BUT its does NOT execute the AWS commands..

What works: I created test-log files and put the aws commands in postStart hook (installS3Script.sh) and it works fine !!

I think I might be looking into preStop hooks differently. I read a few articles on [lifecycle](https://blog.openshift.com/kubernetes-pods-life/) and [preStop](https://pracucci.com/graceful-shutdown-of-kubernetes-pods.html) hook. Also had a relative question on use of [preStop hook with grace period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676124/relation-between-prestop-hook-and-terminationgraceperiodseconds/54680573#54680573).

Any suggestions/help on what I might be missing are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be easier using [Skbn](https://github.com/nuvo/skbn).

> **Skbn** is a tool for copying files and directories between Kubernetes and cloud storage providers. It is named after the 1981 video game  [Sokoban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokoban). Skbn uses an in-memory buffer for the copy process, to avoid excessive memory consumption. Skbn currently supports the following providers:
>   -   AWS S3
>   -   Minio S3
>   -   Azure Blob Storage

You could use:

```
skbn cp \
    --src k8s://<namespace>/<podName>/<containerName>/<path> \
    --dst s3://<bucket>/<path>
```

You should look at [in-cluster](https://github.com/nuvo/skbn/tree/master/examples/in-cluster) usage, as it will require setting up ClusterRole, ClusterRoleBinding and ServiceAccount.

Comment: I am not sure how skbn fits in with what I am trying to achieve ?!

Comment: Just FYI, I added the installScript to transferScript so that I set up aws-cli and execute aws commands altogether in the preStop hook and this works !! Still not sure why I am unable to use postStart and preStop together !?!?